# PHP - Get values for each key from an array that matches ul list value

Tags: php, arrays

I have some product categories which are rendered as unordered list:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li onclick="window.location.href='categories.php?clicked=CEREALS'"><a href="#">CEREALS</a></li>
    <li onclick="window.location.href='categories.php?clicked=RICE'"><a href="#">RICE</a></li>
    <li onclick="window.location.href='categories.php?clicked=WHEAT'"><a href="#">WHEAT</a></li>
</ul>
```

On clicking the category, I am parsing the value in php as an array:

```
<?php
    $category = $_GET["clicked"];
    settype($category, "array");
?>
```

I have created a key value array and trying to use it to get the category value.

```
<?php
    $array1 = array( 
        'CEREALS' => 'TOTALCEREAL', 
        'RICE' => 'RICEOTHERSOURCE', 
        'WHEAT' => 'WHEATPDS' 
    ); 
    $cat = array_intersect($category, $array1);
    echo $cat;
?>
```

I was hoping to get the value for the key in $category, but i am getting only 'Array' printed. What I want is, if I click CEREALS I want to get TOTALCEREALS returned from array1. Any thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you doing it the complicated way?

Your template:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li><a href="categories.php?clicked=CEREALS">CEREALS</a></li>
    <li><a href="categories.php?clicked=RICE">RICE</a></li>
    <li><a href="categories.php?clicked=WHEAT">WHEAT</a></li>
</ul>
```

And your backend php code:

```
<?php
$category = $_GET["clicked"];

$array1 = array( 
    'CEREALS' => 'TOTALCEREAL', 
    'RICE' => 'RICEOTHERSOURCE', 
    'WHEAT' => 'WHEATPDS' 
); 

if(!empty($array1[$category])) {
    echo $array1[$category];
}
```

Comment: Many thanks...this works perfectly. Will accept your answer in 5 mins.